# magento how to add on sale stamp image on a product

Tags: magento

How do we add a On Sale image to a product and display it on the product details page along wiht the category page?

Im using he following code for adding On Sale image in the category list page, and it  gets me the desired result.

```
<?php $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice();  
             if ($specialprice){?> <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/onsale-img.png') ?>" width="68" height="68" class="onsaleicon" />  
            <?php } ?>
```

But im unable to get the same icon to continue onto the PRODUCT details page...

Any suggestions how i can make this happen...

Comment: I dont think you are going to have much luck getting many more answers from the stack overflow community as you don't appear to accept any answers

Comment: thnxs... i completely missed it... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$_product->getSpecialPrice();
```

catalog/product/view.phtml

If you are intrested in commercial check this [extension](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/on-sale.html)

Comment: Thanxs Gowri... im assuming this code alone will work or do i append it and use it along with my code...

Comment: Thank you : Then accept the answer that will help others easy to find a answer.